# DRF Token Authentication: { "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." }

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, token, postman

I am working on a Django e-commerce project.

I tried to implement a token authentication system.
I added `rest_framework.authtoken`to `INSTALLED_APPS` and

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (

        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

to settings file.

Here's my `urls.py`

```
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login_signup/',include('login_signup.urls')),
    path('profile',include('profile_info.urls')),
    path('',include('category.urls')),
    path('cart',include('cart.urls')),
    path('api_token_auth',views.obtain_auth_token,name='auth-token'),
]
```

Here's my `category.urls` file.

```
urlpatterns=[
path('category',CategoryView.as_view(),name='category'),
path('subcategory',SubcategoryView.as_view(),name='subcategory'),
path('product',ProductView.as_view(),name='product'),
path('search',SearchView.as_view(),name='search'),
]
```

I am able to obtain tokens by providing username and password at `api_token_auth` end point.
[image]

Now, I should be able to access any API provided I add Authorization HTTP header in this format. 
Authorization:Token "xyz"

But I keep getting `{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided"}`
[image]

Here is the view I am trying to access.

```
class SubcategoryView(APIView):
       def get(self,request):
           serializer=SubcategorySerializer(Subcategory.objects.all(),many=True)
           return JsonResponse({"subcategories":serializer.data})
```

Why do I keep getting this error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post your category urls file

Comment: @Exprator please see the edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove the `:` from the `Authorization` header value**. The value of the `Authorization` header should look like this:

`Token <token value>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the Token as Header like `Authorization: Token 1740...20`. 
No semicolon after `Token`.
Here is a curl command

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/subcategory/ -H 'Authorization: Token 1740...20'
```